# How to use non-displaying characters like newline (\n) and tab (\t) with jq's "join" function

Tags: json, bash, variables, jq

I couldn't find this anywhere on the internet, so figured I'd add it as documentation.

I wanted to join a json array around the non-displaying character `\30` ("RecordSeparator") so I could safely iterate over it in bash, but I couldn't quite figure out how to do it. I tried `echo '["one","two","three"]' | jq 'join("\30")'` and a couple permutations of that, but it didn't work.

Turns out the solution is pretty simple.... (See answer)

Comment: Sorry to the two people who have already answered this, my original question was poorly worded. I've now edited it for clarity. Specifically, I was just looking for the syntax for using non-displaying characters in the `join` function. Both my original answer (using something like `jq 'join("'$'\30''")'` and @Charles Duffy's answer (using `\uxxxx` syntax like this: `jq 'join("\u001e")'`) work fine. Note that @Charles Duffy's answer has some additional value for iterating.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. Basically, the rule is that to trust that your code will work with future versions of `jq` (which, as peak indicates, may be less lenient in the future about unescaped literals), you should use JSON escaping syntax. BTW, to convert bash escaping to JSON escaping, you can do something like this: `jq -n --arg str $'\030' '$str'`, which outputs `"\u0018"`. Or you can just use that same (`--arg`) syntax to pass the literal in, and use `$str` inside your `jq`. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `jq -j` to eliminate literal newlines between records and use only your own delimiter. This works in your simple case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
data='["one","two","three"]'
sep=$'\x1e' # works only for non-NUL characters, see NUL version below
while IFS= read -r -d "$sep" rec || [[ $rec ]]; do
  printf 'Record: %q\n' "$rec"
done < <(jq -j --arg sep "$sep" 'join($sep)' <<<"$data")
```

...but it also works in a more interesting scenario where naive answers fail:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
data='["two\nlines","*"]'
while IFS= read -r -d $'\x1e' rec || [[ $rec ]]; do
  printf 'Record: %q\n' "$rec"
done < <(jq -j 'join("\u001e")' <<<"$data")
```

returns (when run on Cygwin, hence the CRLF):

```
Record: $'two\r\nlines'
Record: \*
```

---

That said, if using this in anger, I would suggest using NUL delimiters, and filtering them out from the input values:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
data='["two\nlines","three\ttab-separated\twords","*","nul\u0000here"]'
while IFS= read -r -d '' rec || [[ $rec ]]; do
  printf 'Record: %q\n' "$rec"
done < <(jq -j '[.[] | gsub("\u0000"; "@NUL@")] | join("\u0000")' <<<"$data")
```

NUL is a good choice because it's a character than *can't be stored in C strings* (like the ones bash uses) at all, so there's no loss in the range of data which can be faithfully conveyed when they're excised -- if they *did* make it through to the shell, it would (depending on version) either discard them, or truncate the string at the point when one first appears.

Comment: WARNING: This solution assumes either that the JSON in $data does not already contain encoded RS characters, or that such characters should be treated as separators in the same way as the added RS characters.

Comment: Of course -- that's intrinsic in the request itself. (I've taken this approach on occasion in production code, but when I do so, I use NULs as the delimiters, and explicitly filter them out from the values within `jq`).

Comment: @peak, ...I've amended this to show an example with NUL delimiters used.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, would you mind explaining why the `|| [[ $rec ]]` is necessary? And maybe also why setting `IFS=` before read is necessary. Doesn't `read`'s `-d` flag make `IFS` irrelevant?

Comment: @kael, that's because `join()` doesn't put a trailing entry after the last item, and `read` returns a nonzero exit status unless a ending delimiter is present, even though it still populates the destination variable in this case. So without that condition, you lose the last item in your list.

Comment: @kael, `IFS=` and `-d` do two different things: `IFS` controls the *field* separator; `-d` controls the *record* separator. You get one record parsed per `read` call, and that record is broken into fields, the number of which depends on whether there's a `-a` argument, and (if not) the number of positional arguments passed to `read`. Even in the case where there's only one argument, though, characters in `IFS` are trimmed from the fields -- so without `IFS=`, trailing whitespace can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to solve the problem is to use the -c command-line
option, e.g. as follows:

```
echo "$data" | jq -c '.[]' |
while read -r rec
do
    echo "Record: $rec"
done
```

Output:

```
Record: "one"
Record: "two"
Record: "three"
```

### Problems with the OP's proposed answer

There are several problems with the proposal in the OP's answer based on `$'\30'`

First, it doesn't work reliably, e.g. using bash on a Mac
the output is: `Record: "one\u0018two\u0018three"`;
this is because jq correctly converts octal 30 to `\u0018`
within the JSON string.

Second, RS is ASCII decimal 30, i.e. octal 36, which
would be written as `$'\36'` in the shell.
If you use this value instead, the program produces:
`Record: "one\u001etwo\u001ethree"` because that is
the correct JSON string with embedded RS characters.  (For the record `$'\30'` is Control-X.)

Third, as noted by Charles Duffy, "for rec in $(...) is inherently buggy."

Fourth, any approach which assumes jq will in future accept
illegal JSON strings is brittle in the sense that in the
future, jq might disallow them or at least require a command-line
switch to allow them.

Fifth, `unset IFS` is not guaranteed to restore IFS to its state beforehand.

Comment: There's no need to `unset IFS` if one is careful in how one modifies it: `while IFS=$'\x1e' read -r -a recs` scopes the change to the `read`, and won't change the value of `IFS` for any other command.

Comment: Very useful information everyone, thanks. I've now learned not only never to use `for` loops for anything but file lists, but also never to talk about it in public ;P.

Comment: Heh. You can safely use `for` for iterating over arrays too -- `for x in "$@"` or `for x in "${foo[@]}"` are fine, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The RS character is special in jq when used with the `--seq` command-line option.  For example, with a JSON array stored in a shell variable named `data` we could invoke jq as follows:

```
$ jq -n --seq --argjson arg '[1,2]' '$arg | .[]'
```

Here is a transcript:

```
$ data='["one","two","three"]'
$ jq -n --seq --argjson arg "$data" '$arg | .[]' | tr $'\36' X
X"one"
X"two"
X"three"
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Sirrt for the necroposting, but it might help someone:

using jq's flag `--raw-output`:

`["one","two","three"] | jq --raw-output 'join("\t")'` produces `one    two three` (with tab characters)

Answer (score -1):

You simply use bash's `$'\30'` syntax to insert the special character in-line, like so: `echo '["one","two","three"]' | jq '. | join("'$'\30''")'`.

Here's the whole working example:

```
data='["one","two","three"]'

IFS=$'\30'
for rec in $(echo "$data" | jq '. | join("'$'\30''")'); do
    echo "Record: $rec"
done
unset IFS
```

This prints

```
Record: one
Record: two
Record: three
```

as expected.

**NOTE:** It's important not to quote the subshell in the for loop. If you quote it, it will be taken as a single argument, regardless of the RecordSeparator characters. If you don't quote it, it will work as expected.

Comment: The initial `.|` is unnecessary.

Comment: `for rec in $(...)` is inherently buggy. Try reading a record that contains only a `*` -- you'll see it replaced with a list of local filenames.

Comment: ...related: [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)