# Converting JSON response to key value pair using jq

Tags: bash, scripting, jq

So, I am getting a response from an API that I am calling in a shell script in the following form

```
[{"id":100000004,"name":"Customs Clearance Requested"},{"id":100000005,"name":"Customs Cleared"},{"id":100000006,"name":"Cargo Loaded to Vessel"}]
```

I want to create a map out of it that will help me lookup the id's from a name and use it in the shell script. So something like map["Customs Clearance Requested"] would give me 100000004 which I can use further. Can this be done using jq? I am pretty new to shell scripting and jq and got stuck with above thing

Comment: This is very closely related to [converting a json object into a bash associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717277/converting-a-json-object-into-a-bash-associative-array), maybe even an outright duplicate (unless you don't know how to use jq to convert your current JSON format into the one that question's answers use as input).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
json='[{"id":100000004,"name":"Customs Clearance Requested"},{"id":100000005,"name":"Customs Cleared"},{"id":100000006,"name":"Cargo Loaded to Vessel"}]'

declare -A map
while IFS= read -r -d '' name && IFS= read -r -d '' value; do
  map[$name]=$value
done < <(jq -j '.[] | "\(.name)\u0000\(.id)\u0000"' <<<"$json")

declare -p map  # demo purposes: print the map we created as output
```

...emits as output:

```
declare -A map=(["Cargo Loaded to Vessel"]="100000006" ["Customs Clearance Requested"]="100000004" ["Customs Cleared"]="100000005" )
```

...which you can query exactly as requested:

```
$ echo "${map['Cargo Loaded to Vessel']}"
100000006
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `select` function, e.g.:

```sh
data='[{"id":100000004,"name":"Customs Clearance Requested"},{"id":100000005,"name":"Customs Cleared"},{"id":100000006,"name":"Cargo Loaded to Vessel"}]'
jq 'map(select(.["name"] == "Customs Clearance Requested"))' <<< $data
```

It will get all elements which *name* equals `"Customs Clearance Requested"`, e.g.:

```sh
[
  {
    "id": 100000004,
    "name": "Customs Clearance Requested"
  }
]
```

If you want to get the *id* field:

`jq 'map(select(.["name"] == "Customs Clearance Requested")["id"])' <<< $data`

This will output:

```sh
[
  100000004
]
```

Please note that it will return an *array* and not a single element because the search does not know how many results will be found.

If you want to generalize this in a shell function, you could write:

```sh
function get_id_from_name
{
  # $1=name to search for
  local filter=$(printf 'map(select(.["name"] == "%s")["id"])' "$1")
  jq "$filter"
}
```

Then call it like that:

`get_id_from_name "Customs Clearance Requested" <<< $data`

If your data is stored in a file, you could call it this way:

`get_id_from_name "Customs Clearance Requested" < /path/to/file.json`

Comment: Calling `jq` once per item you want to retrieve seems a little unfortunate, vs converting the whole document to a single bash object all at once.

Comment: And injecting data into strings parsed as code (in any language) is a bad idea. If you want to pass variables to `jq`, that's what `--arg` is for. Thus, something like: `get_id_from_name() { jq -r --arg name "$1" 'map(select(.["name"] == $name)["id"]) | .[]'; }`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I assumed that the OP wanted a single result, but now that you mention it I think you’re right that he needs a map built on the bash side.

Answer (score 0):

The following is very similar to @CharlesDuffy's excellent answer but does not assume that the `.name` and `.id` values are NUL-free (i.e., do not have any "\u0000" characters):

```
declare -A map
while read -r name
do
    name=$(sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' <<< "$name")
    read -r id
    map[$name]="$id"
done < <(echo "$json" | jq -c '.[]|.name,.id')
```

The point is that the -j option is like -r (i.e., produces "raw output"), whereas the -c option produces JSON.

This means that if you don't want the .id values as JSON strings, then the above won't be a solution; also, if the .name values contain double-quotes, then you might want to deal with the occurrences of `\"`.

Comment: `echo $json` is not particularly safe -- if that JSON contains `"Hello * World"`, then the `*` will be replaced with a list of filenames in the current directory. Honestly, if there's a need to handle content with NULs safely, the better answer is to filter them out in jq -- remember that bash uses C strings and can't represent literal NULs at all.

Comment: ...the code here would be doubling up literal backslashes, representing tabs as two-character `\t` sequences, and otherwise not be faithfully representing the JSON values as C strings on the shell side.

Comment: See the last code snippet in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51234929/14122 for an example of an answer being deliberately cautious about NUL handling.